# Multiplicity-Constraint in Constraint Programming Solvers

Tags: constraint, constraint-programming, or-tools, minizinc

I need to solve a CSP with a constraint imposing upper bounds on the multiplicity of variables in a list.
More precisely, I need a constraint of the form
`multiplicity(VARIABLES,UPPER_BOUNDS)`, where `VARIABLES` is a list of $n$ variables and `UPPER_BOUNDS` is a list of $n$ (constant) integers, so that the constraint is satisfied if at most `UPPER_BOUNDS[i]` variables take the same value as `VARIABLES[i]`, for $i=1,\ldots,n$.

For example, `multiplicity([1,2,2,3,2,1],[2,3,4,1,3,3])` is satisfied but `multiplicity([1,2,2,3,2,1],[2,2,4,1,3,3])` fails because the second variable (equal to 2) appears 3 times in the list but has a multiplicity bounded by 2.

1. I wonder if there is an out-of-the box constraint available in any CP solver to do that?
2. I am aware of the constraint `(,,)` (cf. [this ref](https://sofdem.github.io/gccat/gccat/Catmost.html#uid14762)), which demands that at most `N` variables in the list `VARIABLES` take the value `VALUE`. What I need is thus a generalization of `atmost` allowing the `VALUE` to be a variable. Then, the multiplicity constraint could be written as `atmost(UPPER_BOUND[i],VARIABLES,VARIABLES[i])`, for $i=1,\ldots,n$. Is there a CP solver supporting a variant of `atmost` allowing a variable in the field `VALUE` ?
3. At the moment, my best guess was to rewrite the multiplicity constraint as a list of  implications
   `VARIABLES[i]=j   implies    atmost(UPPER_BOUND[i],VARIABLES,j)`
   , for all $i=1,\ldots,n$ and all values $j$ that the variables can take. In practice the pruning does not seem to be very efficient with this approach. Is there another get-around that would be more efficient?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you could use a binary variable $$x_{i,j} = \begin{cases}1& \text{if $x_i=j$} \\ 0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ The multiplicity is then just a summation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What "special" constraints a CP solver provides tends to vary by solver. I think it is fairly common, though, for CP solvers to treat logical expressions as equivalent to binary variables. So if $x[]$ is your vector of variables and $b[]$ your vector of upper bounds, you could write something like $\sum_{j\neq i}(x[i] == x[j]) \le b[i].$

Comment: Completely agree. This is another exotic variation on global cardinality. Just encode it with Boolean variables. Even better, do not use integer variables at all, just arrays of Boolean variables.